# Logic app trigger "when a Resource Event occurs" not working

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-eventgrid

I have an Azure Event Topic set for custom events using cloud schema. I also have a logic app with a "When a resource event occurs" trigger. On saving the Logic app I can see that automatically a subscription is created in the Azure Event Topic resource.
When I publish an event I don't see any triggers on logic app at all. On the Event topic side I see that events are getting dropped.

To troubleshoot I created another logic app with http request trigger and then added an event subscription using the webhook option. Now when i publish an event, I see that the logic app with http request trigger works fine but the logic app with "When a resource event occurs" trigger is still not triggered.

Is there any specific configuration that needs to be done to ensure the "When a resource event occurs" trigger works for custom events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of using a Cloud schema (such as a json object), use in the Settings Split Off, see the following screen snippet:

[image]

the following screen snippet shows a received cloud event message:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Roman. I will try this out and provide an update.

Comment: Thank you Roman! that resolved the problem.